# Interview question regarding current study program

Tags: phd, application, interview

I have completed my M.Sc. in mathematics in 2020. I want to do a Ph.D. in maths. After my graduation I worked as a trainee teacher at a science college. The salary was not good enough so my parents made me leave the job. Since a Ph.D. takes a lot of time my parents enrolled me in a B.Ed. program. They have allowed me to try to get admission to a Ph.D. program. So I've applied for Ph.D. programs and I am about to face the interview. My question is, if the interviewer asks me why I am doing B.Ed. if I want to do Ph.D. then what should be the appropriate answer?

Comment: Where is this happening? In much of the world "my parents enrolled me in a B.Ed. program" doesn't and can't happen. If it is a cultural issue then the people interviewing you may have the same cultural norms, or not, depending on place.

Comment: I am from India. My parents thought until I get admission in Ph.D. I should have a professional degree.  It is also partially my fault that I couldn't convince them

Comment: Are you also applying for doctoral studies in India?

Comment: Yes I am applying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to interpret this as I don't know how Indian academics would react to this. But there are some cultures in which parents exert what, in the US, say, would be undue influence on the decisions of their adult children. That may be your case or not, and academics there may be used to adjusting to this or not. So, you might get some local advice on the following suggestion.

It might be possible and acceptable to just say that your parents are trying to influence your future more than is desirable and were manipulating you into another bachelors when your clear, personal, preference is for a doctorate. Get the conversation moving toward your accomplishments in math and your desire to pursue it as a career.

If you were applying other places, say EU or US, people would be likely to accept that explanation.

There are a few other questions here concerning such misplaced parental influence. It can be difficult to "go against" the wishes of domineering parents, but, at some point you need to make your life your own. They (parents) can mean well, but do things that are actually destructive. Courage.

Comment: I agree. I am from India. Here often parents tries to influence careers of students, very unfortunate. I would suggest the OP to choose career path on her own, ofcourse free to consult with right people (e.g., some academics in related field)